# How can I reset the admin password for VSS?

Tags: authentication, vss

I have inherited a VSS server, but do not have the admin password.

How can I reset it?  I have admin login to the box (Win2003 Server).

Answer (score 1):

If you login with your admin account go to start > run > type control userpasswords2
You should be able to reset any passwords from here if your account is an admin

Comment: VSS uses the "Admin" account, which is not a local windows user.

Comment: How about the tool here?
http://victormaceda.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/reset-vss-admin-password-to-blank/